# How to get text and image from a Wordpress post in Unity

Tags: c#, html, wordpress, web, unity-game-engine

I have completed a game recently and I wanted to make a NEWS page on the launcher where it would get the latest post from my wordpress website (https://unirig.wordpress.com/) and display it in a UIText and UIImage, I have heard of the WWW class in Unity but I do not know how to use it in my case, I code in C#.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have heard of the WWW class in Unity but I do not know how to use it
>   in my case, I code in C#.

You google it first. There are many examples out there.

```
IEnumerator readPage(string pageUrl)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(pageUrl);
    yield return www;

    Debug.Log(www.text);
}
```

To call it :

```
StartCoroutine(readPage("http://www.example.com"));
```

[API reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but now i have another problem - Now that I have all the text on the page - How do I extract just the Post Title from the string? Is there anyway to get only the post title? I have certainly googled this to the best of my ability of how to split strings and how to use substrings but nothing seems to help. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ajay You are NOT using a simple webpage. You are using wordpress with thousands of code. This will be hard because you are doing it wrong already. Assuming this is a simple website then you can just search for `<title>blah </title>`. This is not the case here.

Comment: @Ajay The right way to do this to learn php. Add another php script on your website. Maybe something like this: www.ajayweb.com/getpost.php. Now you can connect to it with Unity. In your php code, connect to the database of your wordpress page and read the title and the body of the page. You can send these in Json format and deserialize  it in Unity with `JsonUtility.FromJson` API.

Comment: Useful link for guidance http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort, it has been very helpful. @Programmer